# What is ならぬ Ｍeaning in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

Found ならぬ in the following sentence and am unsure of what it's meaning is.　Also would be nice if anyone provided a total translation for the whole sentence for increased clarity.

「深夜勤帯にゆとり世代ならぬさとり世代の大型新人がやってきました。」

I've read it as something along the lines of "In our employee group, if they(relating to another employee who is quoting a philosopher) aren't  a yutorisedai(person from the more lax Japanese schooling system in the 1980s-2000s), they must've been the satorisedai(generation in which most people gave up their ambitions due to japan's economy at the time) I had such high hopes of who said that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you understand, it means negation.

> [ならぬ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89%E3%81%AC/#jn-165280)
>
> ［連語］《「ぬ」は打消しの助動詞「ず」の連体形》**…でない**。「一方 (ひとかた) ―ご指導」「ただ―事態」

なら comes from the archaic なり (to be).

Thus AならぬB means *not A but B*. Usually, A is something widely known and B is something new (+ perhaps A and B have similar sounds or B is named in a similar fashion to A). In your case, ゆとり世代 has been a cliche to refer to younger generation but now さとり世代 is even younger and the naming is clearly related.